# Getting bad request (#400) on Ajax calls using Yii 2

Tags: jquery, ajax, yii2

This is my code:

```
$(document).on('change', '#tblhotel-int_zone_id', function(e){
    var zoneId = $(this).val();
    var form_data = {
        zone: zoneId
    };
    $.ajax({
        url: "state",
        type: "POST",
        data: form_data,
        success: function(response)
        {
            alert(response);
        }
    });
});
```

This shows:

> Bad Request (#400): Unable to verify your data submission.

And I already have `<?= Html::csrfMetaTags() ?>`. How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

*Note: See [the answer from Skullcrasher](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27126050/getting-bad-request-400-on-ajax-calls-using-yii-2/27248827#27248827) to fix the issue in the correct way as my answer suggests disabling the [Cross-Site Request Forgery](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_(CSRF)).*

---

You have a problem with enableCsrfValidation. To read more about it you can read [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-controller.html#$enableCsrfValidation-detail).

To disable CSRF, add this code to your controller:

```
public function beforeAction($action) {
    $this->enableCsrfValidation = false;
    return parent::beforeAction($action);
}
```

This will disable for all actions. You should probably, depending on the $action, disable it only for specific actions.

Comment: In such context (when no conditions affects on result of disabling) it's no necessity put it into beforeAction. You can just redefine it into your controller like:
public $enableCsrfValidation = false;
But in beforeAction you can specify concrete action for wich validation will be disabled

Comment: correct, this is easist if you want to disable it for a specific action.

Comment: Don't do this! It's disabling of CSRF protection!

Comment: Why is this marked as correct answer? It is not. This is not a solution. It is like removing the door of your home because the key does not work.

Comment: Hence the note to see the better answer, I cannot remove the ckeckmark only the OP can do that. Btw removing the door is a valid way to get into the house, it may not be the best way but it is a way.

Answer (score 30):

As the answer from Mihai P. states, your problem is CSRF validation. It is also true that you could disable the validation for your actions, but this is not considered a good solution.

As you have a problem in your Ajax request with the validation, you could also use a Yii JavaScript function to add the CSRF token to your formdata that you send in the Ajax request.

Just try to add the token to your form data as follows:

```
var form_data = {
    zone: zoneId,
    _csrf: yii.getCsrfToken()
};
```

I hope this helps and you therefore don't have to disable CSRF validation.

In addition to manually add the CSRF token you can check if there is an X-CSRF header set in the request.

Comment: This is the better answer, not mine.

Comment: I'm trying this within a Vue.js (Index.vue file), and it's not working eh, keep getting "Bad request cannot validate your data" (400) error...

Answer (score 9):

Add this code at the bottom of your layout:

```
<script>
    $.ajaxSetup({
        data: <?= \yii\helpers\Json::encode([
            \yii::$app->request->csrfParam => \yii::$app->request->csrfToken,
        ]) ?>
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 7):

Use:

```
var csrfToken = $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr("content");
$.ajax({
    url: 'request',
    type: 'post',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {param1: param1, _csrf : csrfToken},
});
```

More detail: *[Yii2: Using csrf token](https://www.codesiri.com/2015/01/yii2-using-csrf-token.html)*

Answer (score 4):

You need to disable CSRF validation in the *before action* function:

```
public function beforeAction($action) {
    if($action->id == "action name need to disable")
        $this->enableCsrfValidation = false;
    return parent::beforeAction($action);
}
```

Or using the [GET method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol#Request_methods).

Comment: This is not valid, because it increases the risk of suffering a csrf attack.

Answer (score 1):

This works. Change the csrfParam with your own
in Config/main.php

```
'components' => [
    'request'=>[
        'csrfParam'=>"othername"
    ],
    ...
```

Remember that you must include in your requests the token with the same name as you defined in config.

Answer (score 1):

Although it is an old post with alot of answers but there is something missing from all the answers posted, all of them addressed the correct point but when calling the ajax `POST` request along with your data you should use the `yii.js` functions provided

- `yii.getCsrfParam()` to get the parameter name of the token
- `yii.getCsrfToken()` to get the token or actual value of the csrf-token

As if you have different param name for front-end defined inside the `config.php` or `web.php` under the `request` components configurations

```
components=>[
.......
.......
    'request' => [
        'csrfParam' => '_csrf-frontend',
    ],
.......
.......
]
```

then you need to get that name dynamically and the above function help you out.

You should

```
var form_data = {
    zone: zoneId
};
form_data[yii.getCsrfParam()]=yii.getCsrfToken();
```

Answer (score 0):

/backend/config/main-local.php

```
'components' => [
    'request' => [
        'cookieValidationKey' => 'unique code',
        'csrfCookie' => ['httpOnly' => true, 'path' => '/admin/'],
    ],
],
```

/frontend/config/main-local.php

```
'components' => [
    'request' => [
        'cookieValidationKey' => 'unique code',
        'csrfCookie' => ['httpOnly' => true, 'path' => '/'],
    ],
],
```