# Yii2 - "Unable to verify your data submission" on Ajax calls

Tags: php, ajax, yii2

I'm currently to send some Ajax request in my Yii2 application, but I keep getting 'Bad request 500 (Internal server error)' errors in my console.

I'm trying to do something simple and I'm new to AJAX, so just passing data from a text input when I click on a button to my controller and see how it's formatted (through var_dump).

I tried disabling crsf token in beforeAction and it works, but I don't want to disable it.

Here is my Ajax request :

```js
<script>

    // Bind to the submit event of our form
    $(document).on('click', '#sendButton', function() {

        var newMessage = $('#newMessage').val();

        var myUrl = "<?php echo Url::to(['chat/send']); ?>"

        $.ajax({
            url: myUrl,
            type: "POST",
            data: {newMessage: newMessage, _csrf: '<?=\Yii::$app->request->csrfToken?>'},
            success: function(response) {
                console.log("Hooray");
            }
        });

    });

</script>
```

And here is my Yii2 action :

```php
   public function actionSend() {
        $data = Yii::$app->request->post();

        var_dump($data);

        return $this->render('dump');
    }
```

Comment: *"but I keep getting ... Internal server error ...'"*, check your log (<yourAppRoot>\runtime\logs).

Comment: @DefinitelynotRafal "Unable to verify your data submission", that's what the logs says

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why get Unable to verify your data submission error in Yii2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26459419/why-get-unable-to-verify-your-data-submission-error-in-yii2) or [Getting bad request (#400) on Ajax calls using Yii 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27126050/getting-bad-request-400-on-ajax-calls-using-yii-2)

Comment: You could see what's inside the sent body request, to see if  the request is valid, also you can give more details  about yii app error log, to see step by step  what's happening